# 'scanf()' function does not work in C while multithreading

Tags: c, multithreading

Where is the code I have used in a thread.

```
void *input() {
  while (1) {
    if (image_should_take_input) {
      scanf("%s \n", IE_image_command);
      image_should_take_input = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And this code is in the other thread.
This code is in a while loop too.

```
....more code...

if (image_should_show_input_text) {
  printf("-> ");

  image_should_show_input_text = false;
  image_should_take_input = true;
}

...more code...
```

and here is the code I have written in main() function:

```
int main() {
  pthread_t input_thread;
  pthread_t output_thread;
  
  if (pthread_create(&input_thread, NULL, &input, NULL)) return 1;
  if (pthread_create(&output_thread, NULL, &output, NULL)) return 1;
  
  if (pthread_join(input_thread, NULL)) return 1;
  if (pthread_join(output_thread, NULL)) return 1;
  
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is if I run it the '->' prints but a cannot give any input that means scanf() does not function run. Why?

Comment: `printf("-> ")` in one thread and `scanf` in another one seems to be a very bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Why can't you `printf` and `scanf` in the same thread? Just print the `"-> "` first then take input.

Comment: well, I am using a graphics library (OpenGL) along with it. So, it has a render loop (basically a while loop) and if I put a scanf inside that render loop the rendering stops.

Comment: @MubinMuhammad, Don't move the `scanf` call into the render loop. Move the `printf("->")` into the `input_thread`. The purpose of the "->" prompt is to tell the user that the input thread is waiting for them to enter something. It should be printed exactly once before each time the thread starts to wait. Whenever you want the program to always do one thing and then another in sequence, then your program should do both of those things, one after the other, in the same thread.

Comment: FYI: Your _root_ problem here is that your two threads are sharing the `image_should_take_input` variable without using any _synchronization._ There's no guarantee of when, or even _IF_ the `input_thread` will notice after the other thread changes the variable. The simplest way to "synchronize" access to the variable is to protect the variable with a [_mutex_](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutex-lock-for-linux-thread-synchronization/). But, once you've done that, you'll face another problem, which will be caused by your `input_thread` continuously looping and testing the variable instead of...

Comment: ...waiting for a message from the other thread. The _basic_ way to do that in the "pthreads" library is to use a [_condition variable_](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032r/index.html). "Basic," but also tricky. There may be easier, higher-level ways for one thread to wait for another, but I don't know them. I don't write much C code anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not work because you read and/or modify the same variable `image_should_take_input` from different threads without any synchronisation mechanism.

Declaring this variable `volatile` is not enough to provide proper synchronisation.

The `input` thread has a busy loop that runs at full speed all the time, which is very bad practice.

If the purpose of this program is to learn about threads, you need to study locks, mutex and semaphores, otherwise, you should probably not use threads at all.

Comment: Ok, but tell me why this code works?

Comment: ```#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>

bool should_scan = false;
bool should_print = true;

char nothing[128];

void *take_input() {
  while (1) {
    if (should_scan) {
      scanf("%s", nothing);
      should_scan = false;  
      should_print = true;
    }
  }
}

void *show_output() {
  while (1) {
    if (should_print) {
      printf("-> ");
      should_scan = true;
      should_print = false;
    }
  }
} ```

Comment: ```int main() {
  pthread_t input_thread;
  pthread_t output_thread;

  pthread_create(&input_thread, NULL, &take_input, NULL);
  pthread_create(&output_thread, NULL, &show_output, NULL);

  pthread_join(input_thread, NULL);
  pthread_join(output_thread, NULL);
  
  return 0;
}```

Comment: @MubinMuhammad: The code in the comments happens to produce the expected result, but it has undefined behavior so you cannot rely on it to operate this way all the time: depending on the compiler, target, configuration... or other less obvious reasons, the code produced may malfunction and cause any side effects or nothing at all. Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including expected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that I didn't even know much about 'volatile' keyword. After knowing about it, it turns out that it was the solution.

And I also might have to set a timer when the loop actually can run.

Thanks to @chqrlie to point it out.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).